# How to add points to a player in python

Tags: python, addition

Essentially I've made a best-of-three RPS game and wanted to count how many points a player has.

#### Code

```py
import random
import sys

pc_points = 0
player_points = 0

acceptance_of_death = input('welcome to the possibly winable RPS game. Do you dare to attempt this quite possible feat?\nAnswer yes or no\n')


while True:
    if acceptance_of_death =='yes':
        you_will_lose = input('Ok then. Rock, paper, or scissors?\n')

    else:
        print('Ok, your loss.\n')
        sys.exit()

    rps_list = ('rock','paper','scissors')

    result = random.choice(rps_list)

    if result == you_will_lose.lower():
        print("that's a tie, try again.")
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    elif result == 'rock' and you_will_lose.lower() == 'scissors':
        print('PC chooses rock. You lose.')
        pc_points = +1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    elif result == 'scissors' and you_will_lose.lower() == 'paper':
        print('PC chooses scissors. You lose.')
        pc_points = + 1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    elif result == 'paper' and you_will_lose.lower() == 'rock':
        print('PC chooses paper. You lose.')
        pc_points = + 1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    else:
        print("you win! don't get too excited I made this in a very miniscule amount of time.")
        player_points = + 1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    if player_points == 3:
        print('You win. Feel accomplished!')
        sys.exit()

    if player_points == 3:
        print('You lose. Pathetic!')
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)
        sys.exit()
```

I used `player_points` and `pc_points` in order to count the points that a player has gained.
I tried adding points by `player_points = + 1` but that only goes up to player_points = 1 and stays at that value, never increasing over 1.

How can I increase the count higher than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its +=, not =+.

You use

```
x += 1
```

to increment x by 1. You use

```
x = + 1
```

to assign that `x = 1`

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax problem in your assignment.
The correct syntax would be:

```
pc_points += 1
```

Often called [*assignment operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment), Python docs name it [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to sth like the below code snippet:

```py
import random
import sys

pc_points = 0
player_points = 0

acceptance_of_death = input('welcome to the possibly winable RPS game. Do you dare to attempt this quite possible feat?\nAnswer yes or no\n')


while True:
    if acceptance_of_death =='yes':
        you_will_lose = input('Ok then. Rock, paper, or scissors?\n')

    else:
        print('Ok, your loss.\n')
        sys.exit()

    rps_list = ('rock','paper','scissors')

    result = random.choice(rps_list)

    if player_points == 3:
        print('You win. Feel accomplished!')
        sys.exit()

    if pc_points == 3:
        print('You lose. you suck!')
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)
        sys.exit()


    if result == you_will_lose.lower():
        print("that's a tie, try again.")
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    elif result == 'rock' and you_will_lose.lower() == 'scissors':
        print('PC chooses rock. You lose.')
        pc_points += 1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    elif result == 'scissors' and you_will_lose.lower() == 'paper':
        print('PC chooses scissors. You lose.')
        pc_points += 1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    elif result == 'paper' and you_will_lose.lower() == 'rock':
        print('PC chooses paper. You lose.')
        pc_points += 1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)

    else:
        print("you win! don't get too excited I made this in a very miniscule amount of time.")
        player_points += 1
        print(player_points)
        print(pc_points)
```

The changes in your code snippet to run in the correct way are:

1. One of the two `if player_points == 3` should change to `if pc_points == 3` to have a correct result for your game and stop the game on the `3` score of each hand.
2. you should use one of the `pc_points += 1` or `pc_points = pc_points + 1` instructions to increment the points and `pc_points =+ 1` is just a simple assignment like `pc_points = 1`.